# How does Android know which attributes specific views can have in a particular layout?

Tags: java, android, xml

My question is, how does Android know, which attributes an e. g. ImageView can have in a RelativeLayout in XML?
I know that the attributes for that are defined in `android.view.ViewGroup` and its subclasses such as RelativeLayout but how do these attributes go from Java to XML and how does Android know which attributes belong to which view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All attributes for view are located in `declare-styleable` tag in resource files.
Layout attributes, such as `android:layout_gravity` are located in `declare-styleable` tag with a `_Layout` name prefix. For example, `<declare-styleable name="LinearLayout_Layout">`.

If you want to locate them in Android Studio, open *Project* tab in *Project* window, then in *External Libraries/Android Platform/res/values/*. Here `attrs.xml` contains all info about platform views attributes.

To learn more about views read this [documentation article](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#customattr)